# Chrome: How to get rid of "Can't update Chrome" message everytime chrome starts

Tags: google-chrome

I found out that the current chrome version 96 is not compatible with a script that I use. So I uninstalled chrome version 96 and installed version 91. Next I followed a tuturial to stop chrome from updating by disabling "gupdate" and "gupdatem" services and zipping the update folder in chromes Program files foder.

It seems to have worked for the last hours at least chrome didn't update itself. The problem is now every time I start chrome I get a "Can't update Chrome" message. Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Might it not be better to get an updated script? Likely the newer version of Chrome patched a security flaw which that script employs, even though it may not be intended as malware.

Comment: I made the script myself and couldn't get it to work in current chrome version.